# Concatenating tensors in Tensorflow with None axis

Tags: python, keras, concatenation, tensor

I'm concatenating 2 tensors x and y with shape (64,64,1) and (None,64,64,8)

And I got this error message

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(64, 64, 1), (None, 64, 64, 8)]

please

```
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
#the shape of x is (None, 64, 64, 8)

#y is random generated bits tensor
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice([0, 1],(64,64,1)).astype(np.float32()))
z = Concatenate()([x,y],axis=0)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(z)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error actually states what is wrong quite clearly. Two errors in your code and they are not related to the None value in your shape.

- The first shape has only three dimensions while the latter has four. Fix this by reshaping it and adding a 1-sized dimension at axis=0.
- More problematic is the second error. The last dimensions do not match either. 1 is not 8.

Both can be fixed quite easily by generating a random tensor with the correct shape `(1, 64, 64, 8)` (though Im not entirely sure what it is supposed to accomplish?).

Comment: Thank you, but I change it into

Comment: y = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.choice([0, 1],(1,64,64,8)).astype(np.float32()))
z = Concatenate()([x,y],axis=0)

Comment: the result is.  A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 64, 64, 8), (1, 64, 64, 8)]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change anything else? Make sure axis=0 still!

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Im trying use tf.concat() instead